# return of CERT_FindUserCertByUsage in javascript

Tags: javascript, c++, firefox-addon, jsctypes, nss

I am trying to understand the relationship between C++ dll and JavaScript.
There is a js code:

```
cert = CERT_FindUserCertByUsage(certDB, certName.nickname,certUsageEmailSigner, true, null);
```

where cert is defined as

```
let cert = null;
```

However in C++, cert is a struct

```
CERTCertificateStr {
    char *subjectName;
    char *issuerName;
    SECItem derCert;            /* original DER for the cert */
    .... }
```

I am trying to get the subject name  in javascript and I continue the code with

```
let a = cert.contents.subjectName;
```

It is unsuccessful. It logs error as "cannot get content of undefined size"

Anything that i have missed in between C++ and javascript? 
How can i print the subjectName in javascript?

Comment: Can you output the `subjectName` of CERTCertificateStr structure using `puts` function in C++? May be you need to use ASN1 parser for it.

Comment: yes, i can access the subjectName without the need to have asn1 parser in C++

Comment: So you are trying to do js-ctypes? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing jsctypes and you are on the right track. To get the js string though you have to tag on a `readString()` after casting it to an array with a certain length, its ok to go past the actual length as `readString()` will read up till the first null char which is `\x00`. Although if you know the exact length that's always best (you dont have to do the length + 1 for null term) because then you save memory as you dont have to unnecessarily allocate a buffer (array in jsctypes case) more then the length needed.

So try this:

```
let a = ctypes.cast(cert.contents.subjectName, ctypes.char.array(100).ptr).contents.readString();
console.log('a:', a);
```

The error `cannot get contents of undefined size` happens in situations like this:

```
var a = ctypes.voidptr_t(ctypes.char.array()('rawr'))
console.log('a:', a.contents);
```

this spits out

> `Error: cannot get contents of undefined size`

So in order to fix that what we do is this:

```
var b = ctypes.cast(a, ctypes.char.array(5).ptr)
console.log('b:', b.contents);
```

and this succesfully accesses contents, it gives us  (by the way, i used 5 for length which is 4 for the length of `rawr` + 1 for null terminator but i really didnt have to do that i could have used length of just 4)

> `CData { length: 5 }`

so now we can read the `contents` as a js string like this:

```
console.log('b:', b.contents.readString());
```

and this spits out:

> `rawr`

ALSO, you said the functions returns a struct, does it return a pointer to the struct? Or actually the struct? I would think it returns a pointer to the struct no? so in that case you would do this:

```
let certPtr = CERT_FindUserCertByUsage(certDB, certName.nickname,certUsageEmailSigner, true, null);

let certStruct = ctypes.StructType('CERTCertificateStr', [
   {'subjectName': ctypes.char.ptr},
   {issuerName: ctypes.char.ptr},
   {derCert: ctypes.voidptr_t}
]);

let cert = ctypes.cast(certPtr, certStruct.ptr).contents;
let a = cert.contents.subjectName.readString();
```

Comment: It is beautiful. Thank you Noitidart.